# New Command acting around selected text

Tags: macros

I would like to make a new command that allows me to quickly write the expectation value of an operator. It should put text in between other commands to make the following:

```
$\langle \psi | text | \psi \rangle$
```

through using a new command like this:

```
\newcommand{\expectation}{\langle \psi {text} \psi \rangle}
$\expectation{text}$
```

What is the correct way of formatting this?

Comment: `\newcommand{\expectation}[1]{\langle \psi #1 \psi \rangle}`

Comment: Have a look here for examples https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros

Comment: @BambOo, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the braket package. The \Braket macro makes sure that the size gets automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A syntax for a custom macro can be `\newcommand{\<macroname>}[<number of arguments>]{<macro code with #1 as first argument, #2 second ...>}`.

In your case, the macro can be defined as `\newcommand{\expectation}[1]{\langle \psi #1 \psi \rangle}`.

More information can be retrieved from [wikibooks/latex/macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros).
You should also have a look at the [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package which provides enhanced macro definition capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The `mathtools` package provides a way to define such commands.  The documentation contains a definition for `\braket` and you can build on this to get an `\expectation` macro with similar properties, namely that `\expectation*` rescales automatically, and `\expectation`, `\expectation[\big]`, `\expectation[\Big]`, `\expectation[\bigg]`, etc., produce specific sizes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\braket}[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1
\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{} #2 \,\delimsize\vert\, \mathopen{}
#3}

\NewDocumentCommand{\expectation}{ s O{} m }{
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
  { \braket*{\psi}{#3}{\psi} }
  { \braket[#2]{\psi}{#3}{\psi} }
  }

\begin{document}

\( \braket{\psi}{X}{\phi} \) \( \expectation{X} \)

\( \braket{\psi}{A^{2}}{\phi} \) \( \expectation{A^{2}} \)

Manual sizing
\begin{equation*}
  \braket[\bigg]{\psi}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}{\phi}
  \expectation[\bigg]{\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}}
\end{equation*}
\( \braket[\big]{\psi}{A^{2}}{\phi} \) \( \expectation[\big]{A^{2}} \)

Automatic sizing
\begin{equation*}
  \braket*{\psi}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}{\phi}
  \expectation*{\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use the following definition: `\newcommand{\expectation}[1]{\left\langle\psi\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert\psi\right\rangle}`. In this way the size of the angular brackets adapts to the size of the argument.